# LCR, DOWNMIX TO LR

Tags: lcr, pro-tools

i am doing some edit of dialogue on a short movie,I am mixing in LCR and  I have all dialogues at Center and all the rest on LR, now the director want me to render a lr audio to use in the movie  he wants just export from final cut as h264 probably to send to someone via vimeo or whatever. So i have the problem to mix from lcr to Lr with protools 10. What is the best workflow to make the thing properly ?

Comment: "now the director want me to render a lr audio..."  Can't you also just mix in 5.1 and then fold down the printmaster to a standard LoRo (or LtRt if you want)?  LtRt's are pretty standard deliverables in a 6+2 spec.

Comment: just to check, it would be a weird LCR mix if everything except dialogue was LR, surely you have C ambiences as well as LR? and aren't you panning elements (eg FX, Foley) across LCR? a car pass L>R across the screen should actually pan L>C>R

Comment: yes, mostly since this guys have been using only one boom mic forthe whole movie i have dialogue and many many effects in center channel, i am just recreating some effects, rerecording it to put on LR

Comment: but now i am really confused, considering that all effects have been recorded on same dialogue track, how do I "spread" on stereo my effects, there no other way then to record them again? what is the basic rule generally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will take a little bit of work to get it to sound right for your mix, but in essence:

Create a session with 5 tracks in Pro Tools. Put your **L**, **C** and **R** on one each. Your remaining two tracks will be for an **LC** bounce, and an **RC** bounce.

Reduce the level of your **C** track by approx 3dB.

Now, bus the **L** and **C** to **LC** and record, then bus **R** and **C** to **RC** and record.

To monitor; bus **LC** to **Left Speaker** and **RC** to **Right Speaker**, and hear if your **C** components sits well in the mix. If not, adjust the level of your **C** track and repeat until you're happy.

Comment:  can I get the same result creating a send from dialogue channel to the stereo music stem (LR), at least to monitor.

Answer (score 0):

thereis some plug in that makes it properly too? soundcode neyrick for ex.

Comment: I've never used a plugin like that, but I guess it could work. It is essentially doing the same as you'd be doing in my suggestion above. There's no simple 'magic button' to mix three channels to two, it will still need your judgement as to how much of the **C** of your mix is present in your **Left** and **Right** down-mixes.

Comment: thanks, I have created my setup in my setting and will use this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that what the "Downmixer" plug-in is for? Comes free with PT10. Look in the "Sound Field" plug-ins group. I haven't used it, but I think you just make a duplicate master aux channel and insert the plug-in. It turns it into a stereo aux with a downmix.